# ArUco Camera Calibration function arguments type missmatch

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I have a problem running the following code which is based on the ArUco's official [calibrate_camera.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/samples/calibrate_camera.cpp) sample.

```
    cv::aruco::Board arucoBoard;
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
    cv::Size imgSize;
    std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point2f>> allCornersConcatenated;
    std::vector< int > allIdsConcatenated;
    std::vector< int > markerCounterPerFrame;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
    double repError = cv::aruco::calibrateCameraAruco(allCornersConcatenated,
    allIdsConcatenated, markerCounterPerFrame, 
    arucoBoard, imgSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, 0);
```

The problem is that Visual Studio complains that "no instance of the overloaded function matches the argument list", but I cannot see why because the type of the arguments mach the types of the arguments in the official sample.
I get the following message :

`no instance of overloaded function "cv::aruco::calibrateCameraAruco" matches the argument list. argument types are:
(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f, std::allocator<cv::Point2f>>, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point2f, std::allocator<cv::Point2f>>>>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, cv::aruco::Board, cv::Size, cv::Mat, cv::Mat, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat>>, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat>>, int)`

 I need some help to figure out what is going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: How exactly does the compiler "complain"? Believe it or not, the error messages it produces contain a lot of relevant information. | You are incorrect about the arguments matching -- specifically the sample has a [`Ptr<aruco::Board>`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/samples/calibrate_camera.cpp#L214) wheres you only have a `Board`.

Comment: And In fact I really cannot understand how I missed that about  Ptr<aruco::Board> that you mentioned. Please change your comment to answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.